# LTS or Normal Release for 2014

Tags: upgrade, lts

There was a time not long ago when this question would (and should!) of been marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60868/pros-and-cons-of-lts-vs-normal-release) or many others...

But the landscape of Ubuntu has changed since 12.04, and it will again with 14.04.

My question is this:

Who should run the LTS now? Is it just business and servers, or is it now casual users, home users and students as well?

On the other hand, since the regular releases are not as major as they used to be, would they be safe for students and casual users? Could a someone depend on their laptop day in and day out on a regular release?

What are the Pros and Cons of each now?

Specifically I ask because I'm an engineering and physics student. I do a lot of programming, CAD (VMWared SolidWorks), and writing (LaTeX). I want to know whats best for me since I can't have my computer unstable.

Comment: I think it will answer it for anyone who stumbles across this in the future. Thanks for the blast from the past, I'm a Linux sysadmin now. Haha!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 will be the last release to completely rely on x-org. Subsequent versions of Ubuntu will be replaced by [Mir](http://unity.ubuntu.com/mir/) (Canonicals own display server). The road will be bumpy and expect jerks and crashes for the post 14.04 releases. Although x-org will still be there for legacy applications, it will be systematically removed from Ubuntu in later releases.

Another major change the post LTS releases will see is the introduction of [Unity 8](https://launchpad.net/unity8). Now if you remember the early days of Unity(11.04) then expect at least 2-3 releases for Canonical to figure out and squash all the major bugs.

**Verdict**: Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 and stick to it for at least a couple of later releases. Let Canonical work on the major bugs and jump ship when the general community consensus seem that Unity and Mir is stable.